# Is there any minimum monthly payment required towards the margin amount borrowed from your broker?

Tags: margin

When you take a loan from a bank, there is usually a minimum monthly payment that you need to make.

When you take a loan from your broker(use margin), do you need to make a minimum monthly payment towards the borrowed amount?

Or so long as you satisfy maintenance margin, no minimum payment is needed?

Comment: When you say "take a loan from your broker" do you mean "trade on margin"? It is not a loan in any really meaningful sense.

Comment: @MD-Tech Of course it's a loan. You're buying stock with money you don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you trade on margin you only have to ensure that any value at risk is covered by your margin. The guaranteed income to the broker is from the bid-offer spread and from interest they accrue from having your margin. If your posted margin does not cover the full amount that you could lose it will trigger a margin call to make you post more margin against the risk. At the end of day specified by your broker, which could be at end of trading on Saturday (UTC) or could be at a defined time each day (mine is 17:00 UK time), the margin will be recalculated and effectively a rollover will occur; p&l becomes crystallized for the day and your trade is redone.
note that in the real market settlement for the majority of instruments is more than one day  so if the broker buys the instrument (they may not and may just cover it by netting positions) at all they may not have to pay for it if they sell before delivery and net out the settlement of the position using your cash to cover any losses or giving you the cash difference if you are in profit. So long as they have the cash to cover settlement it doesn't matter whether they still hold the instrument at settlement or have sold it on to cover the cost.

Answer (score 2):

You're conflating two issues in your question.

The margin maintenance amount is the minimum amount (total of cash and marginable securities) required in your account to support a margined position.  If the equity falls below that level, you will have to either add cash or marginable securities, assuming that your broker gives you the time to do so.  Today, if in margin violation, brokers tend to close (without asking) enough positions to reduce the margin exposure - and more often than not at unfavorable prices.

If you trade on margin, you borrow money.  Each day, your broker calculates the amount of interest that you owe.  They have the right to take it whenever they want but in general, they take it out of your account at the end of the month, either physically or out of your excess margin.